# Reading unselect values of checkboxes in datatable primefaces

Tags: primefaces

I have a datatable with checkboxes for selection. Values coming from db are shown as checked in the datatable. When a new selection is made by clicking a checkbox I can read the values in the backend from the array, but when I uncheck a checkbox(to deselect that row), that array still contains the checked checkboxes information. I want the array to have only checked checkboxes information at the time of submit(so that I can deleted the unchecked ones from db). Here is the code -

```
<p:dataTable id="stdList"
                             value="#{stdController.students}"
                             selection="#{stdController.selectedStudents}" 
                             var="item"
                             rows="10"
                             rowKey="#{item.id}"
                             >
                    <p:column selectionMode="multiple" />
                    <p:column
                        sortBy="#{item.name}" 
                        filterBy="#{item.name}"
                        filterStyle="display: none;"
                        >
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <h:outputText value="#{prop.name}"/>
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.name}"/>
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
```

My backing bean is -

```
public Topics[] getSelectedStudents() {
    Students[] returnStudents = new Students[getSelectedStudentsAsList().size()]; // //this gets the list from db and creates the array here.
    getSelectedStudentsAsList().toArray(returnStudents);
    return returnStudents;
}

public void setSelectedStudents(Students[] selectedStudents) {
    getSelected().setStudents(new HashSet<Topics>(Arrays.asList(selectedStudents)));
 }
```

Any help is really appreciated.
TIA.

Comment: I forgot to mention, I am using PF RC1 with JSF 2.0

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in JQuery, which affects PrimeFaces and is still not fixed.
Check this: http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=3205
You can use strings as row identifiers as workaround (item.name for example).